# How to define the Microdata markup for an image when it's actually a picture tag?

Tags: html, image, schema.org, microdata, picture-element

Within the http://schema.org/Product scope, I want to define the markup for an image. Usually it looks as follows:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="/path-to-image.suffix" alt="image-description" />
```

However, modern responsive pages use the `<picture>` tag. I tried...

```
<picture itemprop="image">
    <source media="(max-width: ${viewport-size-1})" srcset="/path-to-image-size-1.suffix">
    <source media="(min-width: ${viewport-size-2})" srcset="/path-to-image-size-2.suffix">
    <img src="/fallback-path-to-image.suffix" alt="image-description">
</picture>
```

But it appears not to be accepted by [Google's structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). Adding it to the `<img>` tag within the `<picture>` doesn't seem right to me, as it doesn't highlight the whole context and hence neglects the fact that the image exists in various resolutions...

**What is the right Microdata image markup for `picture` tags?**

Comment: You could probably use a meta tag. Or switch to using json-ld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you want a URL value

You have to specify the `itemprop` attribute on the `img` element, not on the `picture` element:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: ${viewport-size-1})" srcset="/path-to-image-size-1.suffix">
  <source media="(min-width: ${viewport-size-2})" srcset="/path-to-image-size-2.suffix">
  <img itemprop="image" src="/fallback-path-to-image.suffix" alt="image-description">
</picture>
```

The reason is because only certain elements can be used if the Microdata property should have a URL as value, i.e., all elements with `href` or `src` attribute.

### If you want an [`ImageObject`](https://schema.org/ImageObject) value

You have to specify the [`contentUrl`](https://schema.org/contentUrl) property on the `img` element:

```html
<picture itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <source media="(max-width: ${viewport-size-1})" srcset="/path-to-image-size-1.suffix">
  <source media="(min-width: ${viewport-size-2})" srcset="/path-to-image-size-2.suffix">
  <img itemprop="contentUrl" src="/fallback-path-to-image.suffix" alt="image-description">
</picture>
```

---

Specifying the `itemprop` on a `source` element (instead of the `img` element) [is allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-microdata-20180426/#values), too, but it would need to have a `src` attribute.